# How to download a password protected URL using C++ in Linux?

Tags: c++, linux

First of all, i am not trying to hack into anything or anyones e mails.

I am new software engineer and I need to log into company wiki page & download info displayed into a text file or something, so i can search for data i am looking for and make dessions based on what i learned from the wiki page. I do have a user name and password for the wiki page and no need for breaking in.

Issue is, I can not figure out a good way to do this. I am using C++ and operating system is Linux.

Here is what I have so far. This does not issue the uer name and password. Can someone please tell me how to issue usename and password ?

> ```
> string line;
> system("wget www.cooperateweb.com/wikipage/productpage/FWversions+date");
>
> ifstream file ("index.html");
>
> while (!file.eof())
> {
> getline(file,line);
> cout<<line<<"\n";    }    file.close();
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [TFM](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget):

```
 --user=user
 --password=password
    Specify the username user and password password for both FTP and HTTP
    file retrieval. These parameters can be overridden using the --ftp-user
    and --ftp-password options for FTP connections and the --http-user and
    --http-password options for HTTP connections.
```

Answer (score 5):

Same way as with any URL.

```
scheme://username:password@host/path
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#define MAX_CMD_LENGTH 1000;
char cmdBuffer[MAX_CMD_LENGTH];
/* for sake of demonstration */
char *username = "foo";
char *password = "bar";
sprintf(cmdBuffer, "wget --user=%s --password=%s http://www.cooperateweb.com/wikipage/productpage/FWversions+date", username, password);
char *cmd = malloc(strlen(cmdBuffer) + 1);
strncpy(cmd, cmdBuffer, strlen(cmdBuffer) + 1);
system((const char *)cmd);
free(cmd);
```

Comment: Host i am trying to access turned out to be a class 3 secure server and does not like what I was doing. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Add `--debug --verbose` to your command and post a transcript of what you see to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way, IMHO, is to use curl.  Curl is a more sophisticated web client than wget.

The best way, perhaps, depending on your needs, is the Boost based cpp-netlib.